# Can any tool generate xsd from xml?

Tags: java, xml

I am wondering if there is tool to infer xsd from xml using Java?

Comment: Did you try to ask google? It shows up a nice possibility [Generate XSD from XML - trang](http://www.dotkam.com/2008/05/28/generate-xsd-from-xml/) as the second link for "xsd from xml".

Comment: Nope, the second link on my Google is here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [xmlspy](http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html).
It is a very handy tool for xml stuffs.

There are inevitably free tools to do this as well.

Prasheel Oggu suggests http://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html

I've never used that tool,
so I neither recommend nor suggest against it.

Comment: As is OxygenXML (I've been using it for 18m) - & its cross platform.

Answer (score 1):

I have had good success with the utility: **inst2xsd** which is provided by **xmlbeans**.
You can read more about it at the Apache website: [xmlbeans.apache.org](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) (with the direct link to inst2xsd documentation [here](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/guide/tools.html#inst2xsd). The tool is free.

The tool is easy to use and comes with plenty of options, which have always met my requirements.

Basic usage is: inst2xsd [file.xml]

Example XML (car.xml):

```
<XML>
<Car>
<Headlight>true</Headlight>
<Wheels count="4">Black</Wheels>
</Car>
<Car>
<Headlight>true</Headlight>
<Wheels count="4">Black</Wheels>
</Car>
</XML>
```

This will produce the following file: schema0.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="XML" type="XMLType"/>
  <xs:complexType name="WheelsType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="count" use="optional"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="CarType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Headlight"/>
      <xs:element type="WheelsType" name="Wheels"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="XMLType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element type="CarType" name="Car" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try `trang`.  on debian/ubuntu it's easily installed:

`sudo apt-get install trang`

not the most polished piece of software I've seen, but it did its job here.

since it's pure Java, it should not be difficult to install it on other systems.

ubuntu 11.04 offers a version that is timestamped as 20091111, while http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html mentions 20081028 as newest available version.  I did not try to understand the reason of this.