# Create XSD from Java bean or from XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

I am using this code

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookdata.class);
Bookdata bookdata=new Bookdata();
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
marshaller.marshal(bookdata, (OutputStream) output);
```

But it is generating XML But i need XSD
I Need to create XSD like this:

```
<ArrayOfCommandInfoDTO>
     <CommandInfoDTO>
        <a:allowAddingGameCenterFriends>true</a:allowAddingGameCenterFriends>
        <a:enter code here>allowAppInstallation>true</a:allowAppInstallation>
        <a:allowAssistant>true</a:allowAssistant>
        <a:allowAssistantWhileLocked>true</a:allowAssistantWhileLocked>
        <a:allowCamera>true</a:allowCamera>
     </CommandInfoDTO>
</ArrayOfCommandInfoDTO>
```

So Please tell me how to create XSD from java Beans or from XML

Comment: Refer this.. http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_jaxbjava2schema.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5239284/can-any-tool-generate-xsd-from-xml

Comment: @GV but i need to implement this in Web Application.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ObjToSchema {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        (JAXBContext.newInstance(Bookdata.class)).generateSchema(new DataSchemaOutputResolver());
    }
}


public class DataSchemaOutputResolver extends SchemaOutputResolver {
    @Override
    public Result createOutput(String arg0, String arg1) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new StreamResult(new File("d:/data.xsd"));
    }
}
```

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `generateSchema` method on `JAXBContext` to generate an XML schema.

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/JAXB/GenerateSchema